# Как задать синоним имени метода?

Tags: c++

Есть класс, там определён шаблонный метод, как можно задать несколько синонимов этого метода с различными параметрами шаблона?

```
class CodeContainer {
public:
  template <class T>
  Code* AddCode(const std::string name, int code);

  Code* AddCodeInteger(const std::string name, int code) {
    return AddCode<int>(name, code);
  }
  Code* AddCodeFloat(const std::string name, int code) {
    return AddCode<double>(name, code);
  }
  Code* AddCodeString(const std::string name, int code) {
    return AddCode<std::string>(name, code);
  }
  Code* AddCodeBoolean(const std::string name, int code) {
    return AddCode<bool>(name, code);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна задача, в вашем коде шаблонный параметр нигде не используется. Если вы имеете ввиду [специализацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/template-specialization-cpp?view=msvc-160) шаблонов, то можно сделать так:

```
template <typename T, int size>
void print(StaticArray<T, size> &array)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
    std::cout << array[count] << ' ';
}

template <> // Специализация шаблона
void print(StaticArray<char, 14> &array)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < 14; ++count)
    std::cout << array[count];
}

template <int size> // Частичная специализация шаблона
void print(StaticArray<char, size> &array)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; ++count)
    std::cout << array[count];
}
```

Comment: Нужен синоним имени, может быть, указатель на метод, как синоним имени класса, который можно определить с помощью using

Comment: @Максим под синонимом вы имеете ввиду псевдоним? typedef? Псевдоним чего вам нужен? Что вы вообще хотите сделать? Немного подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: @Максим если вы имеете ввиду псевдонимы шаблонов, то вот: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: псевдоним, чтобы по заданному имени вызывался метод с определёнными параметрами шаблона, чтоб не надо было определять метод с вызовом шаблонного метода.

Comment: @Максим я не самый лучший программист, но как я знаю нельзя просто взять и сделать псевдоним на шаблонный метод/функцию. Можно сделать псевдоним на указатель на функцию. Но мне кажется самый лучший метод - это написать обертку вокруг вызываемой функции. https://web-answers.ru/c/psevdonim-shablonnoj-funkcii.html